# PHP "INSERT INTO" not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, get

I am trying to use "INSERT INTO" function of PHP, but for some unknown reason, it is not working.

Here is the main part of code -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order (t_from, t_to, t_date, t_time, t_payment, t_sn, t_u_email) 
        VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')";
```

What is wrong in this ?

Please help out !

Thanks,

Comment: Try to put ` around your column names!

Comment: `order` is a MySQL and SQL reserved word.  It is a really bad name for a table.  If you have to use it, surround it by backticks.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`order` is a MySQL reserved keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html

Either change `order` to something else,

OR put a backtick around `order`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (t_from, t_to, t_date, t_time, t_payment, t_sn, t_u_email) 
        VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')";
```

Another solution to this would be to use Database name before the table name.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DB_NAME.order (t_from, t_to, t_date, t_time, t_payment, t_sn, t_u_email) 
            VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')";
```

Comment: you can also use 'dbname.order'. I think it works as well.

Comment: @AshishGogna, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Comment: Hi @AshishGogna, please accept my answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you can't name a table like *order*. That is a reserved MySQL Keyword.

In your case you should rename your table to **orders**. That is much butter because there are more then one order in your table and you have solved the problem.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (t_from, t_to, t_date, t_time, t_payment, t_sn, t_u_email) 
        VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')";
```